# Is there any workaround to running mixed content?

Tags: javascript, https, xmlhttprequest

I have a page that's served over HTTPS.  Now I need to make a XMLHttpRequest call to a HTTP resource.  As you would expect, this fails because the browsers will stop these calls in a mixed content situation.  The HTTP resource is a 3rd party and I can't convince them to make their service HTTPS.

What are my options?  Are there any workarounds I might be able to use.

Comment: "proxy" the requests through your server

Comment: Yes same origin will prevent it. You have to proxy it through your server.

Comment: @JaromandaX I wish I could.  I am running one of their js libraries client-side and that is what makes the HTTP XMLHttpRequest call.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a bad, bad, bad security practice and I would not recommend to do that. Or you should ask yourself if you really need secure HTTP.

Please visit this resource: [Mixed Content: Blockable Content (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/#category-blockable)